# Trying to install npm through npm i, getting errors

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install npm to run a server through node js. I do have node --version: v16.16.0 installed. Running npm i, and getting this response form in the terminal window. I have tried launching npm start but it does not start running the server. At first, it gave me sh: cross-env: command not found error, but I have installed cross-env, yet it still does not run the server, gives me this error:

```
node:events:505
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
```

Then

```
Error: spawn gulp ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

and then

```
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn gulp',
  path: 'gulp',
  spawnargs: [ 'start' ]
}
```

Here is the terminal response when I run npm i

```
MacBook-Air-4:mazuri gonastarevgrigory$ npm i
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated @stylelint/postcss-markdown@0.36.2: Use the original unforked package instead: postcss-markdown
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/gonastarevgrigory/Desktop/mazuri/website/mazuri/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node /Users/gonastarevgrigory/Desktop/mazuri/website/mazuri/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/Users/gonastarevgrigory/Desktop/mazuri/website/mazuri/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.16.0 | darwin | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/gonastarevgrigory/Desktop/mazuri/website/mazuri/node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/gonastarevgrigory/Desktop/mazuri/website/mazuri/node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/gonastarevgrigory/Desktop/mazuri/website/mazuri/node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/gonastarevgrigory/Desktop/mazuri/website/mazuri/node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/gonastarevgrigory/Desktop/mazuri/website/mazuri/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/gonastarevgrigory/Desktop/mazuri/website/mazuri/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/gonastarevgrigory/Desktop/mazuri/website/mazuri/node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/gonastarevgrigory/Desktop/mazuri/website/mazuri/node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/gonastarevgrigory/Desktop/mazuri/website/mazuri/node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/gonastarevgrigory/Desktop/mazuri/website/mazuri/node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/gonastarevgrigory/Desktop/mazuri/website/mazuri/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/gonastarevgrigory/Desktop/mazuri/website/mazuri/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python /usr/local/bin/python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /usr/local/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:398:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.5.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/gonastarevgrigory/Desktop/mazuri/website/mazuri/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/gonastarevgrigory/Desktop/mazuri/website/mazuri/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.16.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/gonastarevgrigory/.npm/_logs/2022-07-21T06_32_40_329Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: I believe note-gyp needs to be at least version 7, not 3.8 as in the log or it will require python2 which is no longer supported. I would try updating.

Comment: I ran npm install -g node-gyp, and updated it to v9.1.0. Still getting the same response from the terminal.